# Does energy of photon change due to some external magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity, photons, magnetic-fields

I came to know about the [energy of photon changes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21228/wavelength-of-photon-changes-as-it-rises-from-a-planets-surfaceacc-to-this-eq) (decreases) while going away from the emitter (even from earth) due to gravitational field effects.

Is there any change in energy/wavelength of a photon due to some external (artificial) magnetic field or electric field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electromagnetic fields [generate gravity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136752/does-gravity-affect-magnetism-vice-versa-or-do-they-ignore-each-other), and therefore the answer is **yes**: the energy of a photon changes as it moves through a non-homogeneous electromagnetic field.